# Adjust size and placement of \diameter symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, positioning

I'm trying to match the size and placement of `\diameter` (from `wasysym`) with that of `\circ`. I want the two symbols horizontally aligned with the same size circle. Any suggestions?

MWE:

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
vii$^\circ$ vii$^{\diameter}$ vii\textdegree\ Start of a fix?: vii{\tiny{$^{\diameter}$}}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Might it be easier with `textcomp`'s `\textdegree`? I included that in the MWE as well.

Comment: Do you need other symbols from wasysym?

Comment: Not currently, and I don't see that changing, no. I also added in the possibility of \textdegree in the original.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `\diameter`, you can build the symbol yourself:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{pict2e}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\slashcirc}{{\mathpalette\doslashcirc\relax}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\doslashcirc[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$#1\m@th\circ$}%
  \setlength\unitlength{\wd\z@}
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \put(0,0){\box\z@}
  \put(0,0){\line(1,1){1}}
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
vii$^\circ$ vii$^{\slashcirc}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some small fine tuning might be needed.

Comment: I'm continually amazed at what you guys can do. Thanks so much!